# I need help resolving some errors in my project flutter that uses discord_api

Tags: flutter, api, discord, discord.js

The following errors are appearing:

> The named parameter 'clientId' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> The named parameter 'clientSecret' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> The named parameter 'discordHttpClient' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> The named parameter 'redirectUri' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
> The method 'connect' isn't defined for the type 'DiscordClient'.
> The method 'disconnect' isn't defined for the type 'DiscordClient'.
> The method 'getChannel' isn't defined for the type 'DiscordClient'.

follow the complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:discord_api/discord_api.dart';

const String token = 'sua-chave-de-api-aqui';
const String clientId = 'seu-client-id-aqui';
const String clientSecret = 'seu-client-secret-aqui';
const String redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8080/callback';

void main() async {
  final client = DiscordClient(token);

  await client.connect();

  runApp(MyApp(client));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final DiscordClient client;

  const MyApp(this.client);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final String _channelId = 'id-do-canal-aqui';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.client.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _sendMessage() async {
    final channel = await widget.client.getChannel(_channelId);
    await channel.sendMessage(_controller.text);

    _controller.clear();
  }
}
```

I'm trying everything but I have no results.

Answer (score 0):

The first error messages tells you, that your code cannot be compiled because the constructor of `DiscordClient` needs some arguments that you didn't provide.
. According to [the documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/discord_api), you will have to instantiate your `DiscordClient` like this

```dart
final _discordClient = DiscordClient(
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret,
  redirectUri: redirectUri,
  discordHttpClient: DiscordDioProvider(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret),
);
```